# Reflux Error triggering an action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux, refluxjs

This is either a big bug or I'm having trouble understanding the usefulness of having different view (React) handlers for different actions triggered by the store if all handlers are being called for each of those actions.

Here's what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/10946/

Expected output:

```
action 1 handler triggered from action 1
-----------------
action 2 handler triggered from action 2
```

What I actually get:

```
action 1 handler triggered from action 1
action 2 handler triggered from action 1
-----------------
action 1 handler triggered from action 2
action 2 handler triggered from action 2
```

Just by looking at this output I can say this is wrong. But to clarify: action 1 should only trigger the handler for action 1 and action 2 should only trigger the handler for action 2.

Am I doing something wrong?

Please help!

P.S: I also tried manually using ComponentDidMount with this.listenTo; same behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually, I think you have slightly misunderstood Flux. The component doesn't listen for actions/events, it listens for changes in the data in your store. Therefore what you're seeing is correct, since in both cases you are using `trigger` to indicate that the store has changed.

The component only cares about *firing* actions, not consuming them. Therefore labelling `onAction1` and `onAction2` in the component as "handlers" isn't really correct.